# why my program don't recognize the .txt file

Tags: java

I try to made a program which print the top 20 frequently words in a text file in java, and i have 3 classes but i don't know why can not compile it help me please. I show you the tree classes just to have an idea:

1) 
public class Client {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();

    while(file.hasNext()){//Este lazo lee las palabras y crea el TreeMap
        String word= clean(doc.next());
        Integer count = frequencies.get(word);
        if(count==null){
            count = 1;}
        else {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }
    Object[] Claves =  frequencies.keySet().toArray();
    Object[] Valores = frequencies.values().toArray();
    Par[] par = new Par[frequencies.size()];

    for (int i=0;i<frequencies.size();i++){
        Par p = new Par(Claves[i].toString(),(int) Valores[i]);
        par[i]=p;
    }
    Arrays.sort(par);
    showResult(par);
}
public static void showResult(Par[] arreglo){
    System.out.println("The 20 most frequently words are ");
    for(int i= 0; i<=19; i++){
        System.out.print("Word "+ arreglo[i].Clave + " in " + arreglo[i].Valor + " times.");
    }
}
```

}
2)
public class Par implements Comparable {
    String Clave;
    int Valor;
    public int length;

```
public Par(String clave, int valor){
    this.Clave = clave;
    this.Valor = valor;
}

public int compareTo(Par p) {
        if(this.Valor<p.Valor){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(this.Valor==p.Valor){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }           
}
```

}
3)
public class ProcessText {

```
public void reader(Path r){
    String name = clean(file.getName());
        if(file.getName().equals(name + ".txt" || file.getName().equals(name + ".doc" ))){
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(r)){
                String doc = "";
                while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                    String linea = (sc.nextLine());
                    doc = doc.concat(linea + "\n");
                }
                sc.close();
            }
        }
}

public static String clean(String s){
    String r = "";
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isLetter(c)){
        r = r + c;
        }
    }
    return r.toLowerCase();
}
```

}

Comment: A todos los votantes. Sí, ya sé que está en ingles. No vuelvan a cerrar la pregunta. Si la abrí es por un muy buen motivo.

Comment: Why you can't compile it? What are the error messages?

Comment: vote to close this question

Answer (score 0):

If this is all the code you have, your problem might be that your main method never creates a variable called "doc" or "file", but you use them both at the beginning of Client's main method.

It would be more helpful if you could share the compile time error, though, so I can't be sure that this is your problem.